# Using IDA Pro, How can I just "edit" values, Rather than patching Offsets,

Tags: ida, assembly, ios

I dont understand how people are finding offsets, So I want to know if there's a simple and easy method of just "patching values"

I've been surfing the internet looking for VERY in depth tutorials on editing Assembly for ios apps, but it seems that either the tutorials are too difficult and vague, or are broken and old.

for example, how can I patch this function so it returns true rather than false:

```
; bool __cdecl -[ScrollingListTradePortal everythingFree](ScrollingListTradePortal *self, SEL)
__ScrollingListTradePortal_everythingFree_
ADRP            X8, #_OBJC_IVAR_$_ScrollingListTradePortal.everythingFree@PAGE ; bool everythingFree;
LDRSW           X8, [X8,#_OBJC_IVAR_$_ScrollingListTradePortal.everythingFree@PAGEOFF] ; bool everythingFree;
LDRB            W8, [X0,X8]
AND             W0, W8, #1
RET
; End of function -[ScrollingListTradePortal everythingFree]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the binary in IDA View (assembly view). Place the cursor in the line that you want to patch. Click Edit in menu bar > Patch Program > Change bytes.

[image: edit-patch-program-option]

Switch to "Hex View". Match the assembly mnemonic with the HEX value. This vary with every instruction. For example, `cmp [rbp-4], 4` (in X86_64) is shows as `83 7D FC 04`.

Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit in hex view. Edit the value. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> another time to apply the change. Check the IDA view to review the change. Now go to Edit > Patch Program > Apply patches to input file.

[image: apply-patches-to-input-file]

You can also choose to create a backup.

Similar question: [StackOverflow: Edit (patch) a binary file in IDA Pro
Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/969901/8928481)

Comment: thankyou, I will try this out later tonight, On my school pc during the daytime.

Also, is there a way to identify which of the list of bytes represents the value?
I know that this: "AND             W0, W8, #1" represents TRUE if your on creative mode.

But Im not entirely sure which one to patch if say I just want the value to ALWAYS return true.